# How do I prevent Vim from showing my terminal when executing an external command?

Tags: terminal, external-command

I'm running a long, blocking command using `execute` in Vim as part of a script. Vim shows the underlying terminal while executing the command, which is pretty distracting.

```
function! DoSomething(query)
  execute "silent grep! " . a:query
endfuntcion
```

I use the output in a latter part of the script, so running it asynchronously using `&` is out of the question. Is there any way to make Vim hang while executing the command without going back to the terminal?

Comment: you could run it asynchroneouly, using jobs (have a look at `:h job_start()`). Alternatively, see if `:set guioptions+=!` helps

Comment: Agreed with @ChristianBrabandt; just because you need the output for a later part doesn't mean it can't be async.

Comment: Is the example actually what you're doing? Or just a different command that displays the same behaviour? I ask because I'm confused by a). how you would use `&` to achieve async in that example. What is your `'grepprg'` set to?, and b). how you use the output of that function later in the script. By interacting with the quickfix?

Comment: Also, is it distracting because of the switch to the terminal, or because there is lots of output in that terminal?

Comment: Different use care here, but `:set guioptions+=!` is destructive for async use-cases (gvim). Specifically, processes made with the option set cannot be disowned - disowned processes get killed. Possibly relevant issue: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3327